# Difference for <? super/extends String> in method and variable declaration

Tags: java, generics, collections, extends, super

Given:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Hancock {
    //insert code here
        list.add("foo");
    }
}
```

Which two code fragments, inserted independently at line 5, will compile without warnings? (Choose two)

```
A. public void addString(List list) {
B. public void addString(List<String> list) {
C. public void addString(List<? super String> list) {
D. public void addString(List<? extends String> list) {
```

Correct answers are B & C.

Answers A and B are quite clear for me. For the answers C & D i know which way the inheritence is going, however i cannot understand why answer D does not compile in Eclipse while all others do (A with warrning about generic, B & C without warrings).

Error in Eclipse for answer D is `The method add(capture#1-of ? extends String) in the type List<capture#1-of ? extends String> is not applicable for the arguments (String)`.

On the other hand this compiles:

```
public void addString() {
    List<? extends String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<? super String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

Why? Why `<? super String>` does not compile in method declaration while it does compile in variable declaration.

I know that `String` is final class and cannot be extended by any other class but that does not explain to me what is going on here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Generics: What is PECS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, let's see answer C:

```
public void addString(List<? super String> list) {
    list.add("foo");
}
```

This method declaration says that you will be allowed to pass `List` objects which are parametrized by some super class of `String`, for example `String` or `Object`. So:

1. If you pass `List<String>` the `list.add("foo")` will be perfectly valid.
2. If you pass `List<Object>` the `list.add("foo")` will be perfectly valid, because "foo" is a `String` (and you can add a `String` to a  `List<Object>`).

This means that answer C is correct.

---

Lets now see answer D.

If you have a method declaration like this:

```
public void addString(List<? extends String> list) {

}
```

this means that you will be able to pass `List` objects parametrized by **some unknown** subtype of `String`. So, when you do `list.add("foo");` the compiler won't be aware if the provided object has a type that matches the *unknown* subtype of `String` and therefore raises a compile-time error.

---

When you have:

```
public void addString() {
    List<? extends String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<? super String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

This fragment compiles fine, because `list1` is defined to hold `List` objects that are of some unknown subtype of `String`, including the `String` itself, which is why it's valid.
The problem is that you **won't be able to add anything**, except `null`.

As for `list2`, the variable can hold `List` objects which are parametrized by some super-type of `String`, including the `String` itself.

---

More info:

- [What is PESC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)
- [What is the difference between super and extends in Java wildcards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Comment: Actually your explanation of "C" is wrong. You *cannot* add an `Object` to a `list<? super String>`. The list *could* be a `List<String>` during runtime, so this will fail.

Comment: I disagree. Try `List<? super String> list = new ArrayList<Object>();` and pass it to the `addString` method.

Comment: your example adds a `string` (which is the only valid thing you can add). If you try to add an object, you'll get: `no suitable method found for add(Object) myList.add(new Object());`

Comment: Read carefylly what I've written and tell me where do I say that you can add `Object` instances? I've said that you can pass `List<Object>`, not that you can add `Object`s :)

Comment: touche. How did you remove that comment about "add" - even from the revision history :P

Comment: I think that PECS is the explanation i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, generics don't care that `String` is final. They work the same way for final and non-final classes.

With that in mind, it should be apparent why D is not allowed - if it was, you could do this:

```
void test() {
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    addADouble(integers);
    int a = integers.get(0); // ????
}

void addADouble(List<? extends Number> list) {
    list.add(new Double(5.0));
}
```

`List<? extends Number>` is a "List of something that extends Number, but you don't know exactly what it's a List of." - it might be a `List<Double>`, or a `List<Integer>`, or a `List<Number>`, or a `List<YourCustomSubclassOfNumber>`, so you can't add anything to it because you don't know if it's the right type.

Comment: now i may complicate it a bit more ;)
`System.out.println(new Double(5.0) instanceof Number);` returns `true`, so why `list.add(new Double(5.0));` does not compile in you code with simmilar error i've described in question?
Does `?` in `<? extends Number>` stand for something that returns `true` from above print?

Comment: @Dave I guess my explanation sucks then. You can't add a `Double` to a `List<I don't know what goes here except that it extends Number>`. To use a different example: you can't do `List<? extends Object> list = new ArrayList<String>(); list.add(new Double(5.0));`