# compile time error while using wildcard in List

Tags: java, list, wildcard

```
List<? extends String> list = new Arraylist<String>();
list.add("foo");
```

Given piece of code gives me compile time error.i don't get it why i can't add string in list.
but the code means that we can add the String class object and it's derived class object in the list
still i am getting the error why

Comment: It doesn't really make sense, since `String` is a **final** class! There is no class which can extend `String`. So, the only thing you should do is define it as `List<String>`.

Comment: but how it's taking the reference of the ArrayList which has String as it's object?

Comment: Because `List<String>` satisfies `List<? extends String>`. The difference is *String is a String* but *String may not be a ? that is a String*.

Comment: http://bayou.io/draft/Wildcard_Case_Studies.html#Tight_Bound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<?>` should only be used when you are not concerned with the data type of the items and interested in operations such as getting size of list etc.

For Example,

```
public int getSize(List<?> itemList) {
     return itemList.size();
}
```

It is more of a `Read Only` list.

You should be using the following if you intend to make a new list of `String` items.

```
List<String> list = new Arraylist<>();
list.add("foo");
```

Alternatively, you can use this:

```
List<Object> list = new Arraylist<>();
list.add("foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
List<? super String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("foo");
```

Then your compiler will now, that the caller is to pass a list of objects that are `String` or a super type.

When you say `<? extends String>` it means it can be of any type which extends `String`. That means somebody can pass `List` and it will accept it.

Look also here:
[Difference for <? super/extends String> in method and variable declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861758/difference-for-super-extends-string-in-method-and-variable-declaration)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially `List<? extends String>` is a List of an unknown type, all that is known is that this type extends String. It does not matter that the variable contains an instance of `List<String>`.

Now String is final, so there is no subclass... so let's consider:

```
List<? extends A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
```

where `A` is some class with a subclass `B`. When used, a variable of type `List<? extends A>` might be an instance of `List<B>`. We can not add `A` to it because there is the possibility that an `A` is not a `B`.

But you know it will be right? **Well, the compiler doesn't**, nor does it anticipate the logical connections between the unknown type and what you've instantiated, because in general you may change that variable at runtime.

*A similar example exist in the tutorial optimistically named [More Fun with Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html), where a method accepts `(Set<T>, T)` and an illegal call is preposed using `(Set<?>, String)` though the `Set<?>` variable contains an instance of `Set<String>`. The issue is the same here, despite the addition of `extends`.*