# Why does this generic piece of code give a compilation error

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

Can Some one please explain why the line no. 12 gives a compile time error ?

```
package com.soflow;

import java.util.List;

public abstract class Shape {
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
    private int x, y, width, height;

    public void addRectangle(List<? extends Shape> shapes) {
        shapes.add(0, new Rectangle()); // compile-time error!
        }
}
```

What I am failing to understand here is that why is it not allowing me to add a subtype of shapes into the "shapes" list ? And why is it complaining at compile time ?
I believe compiler can see that there exists an IS-A relation between Rectangle and Shape. I am confused now.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Maneesh Sharma

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098976/compile-time-error-while-using-wildcard-in-list

Answer (score 3):

`List<? extends Shape>` means a list parametrized with *any* subclass of `Shape`, not a list accepting any subclass of shape as its contents. That would just be a `List<Shape>`.

Imagine that `shapes` was a `List<Triangle>` at runtime. This would clearly be an error, since you can't add a Rectangle to a `List<Triangle>`.

However, let's consider why `List<Rectangle>`, `List<Shape>` or `List<? super Shape>` would be correct here. In the first case, it's clear: A `List<Rectangle>` would accept instances of `Rectangle`. In the second, since all `Rectangle` instances are assignable to `Shape`, they can be put into a `List<Shape>`. In the third case, the bound guarantees that the list will accept `Shape` by being a superclass of Shape.

Remember the following phrase: "producer extends, consumer super". Here the list is a *consumer* of added items, so it needs to be `super`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `List<? extends Shape> shapes` to `List<? super Shape> shapes` or `List<Shape> shapes`.